Second order tangent bundle as an associated bundle?
For an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ we have the bundle of second-order frames and the bundle bundle of second order tangent vectors. Can the bundle of second-order tangent vectors be considered as the associated bundle to the bundle of second-order frames, in a similar way as it is done for first-order structures? I will appreciate a suggestion of a textbook dealing with this and similar issues.

Yes this can be done. In my opinion the simplest description of this is by viewing all the bundles in question as jet bundles. The best source I know is the monograph by I. Kolar, P. Michor, and J. Slovak, which is available online at https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf .

Thanks for the hint! This encourages me to ask the follow up question: on a Riemannian manifold we have Fermi transport of first order frames along curves (Hawking, Ellis, The large scale structure of space-time, p. 80) . If we have a conformal connection in the bundle of second order frames, is there known a similar transport formula  for second order frames?

I don't know the terminology you are using, for example, how what you call Fermi transport is related to parallel transport with respect to the Levi-Civita connection. In any case, a conformal structure on a manifold determines a Cartan geometry, which induces a parallel transport of "adapted frames" which probably extends to the full second order frame bundle. But this is a long and involved story.

Thanks. I know that much. Fermi transport, other term Fermi-Walker transport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Walker_transport. I wondered if someone tried to adapt it to second order frames and the connection induced there by the conformal structure. But it seems that this is not the main concern for mathematicians, and physicists are not yet there. Anyway thanks for listening!
